# SQL Get Users By One Group But Exclude Others

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to write a query that get's all users that belong to Group `A`, but excludes users that belong Groups `B`, `C` & `D`.

Users can belong to multiple groups.

I have the following query but it's not working:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN groups USING (user_id)
WHERE groups.name = 'A'
AND groups.name NOT IN ('B', 'C', 'D')
```

This just selects all users from group `A`, how do I exclude anyone who also belongs to groups `B`, `C` & `D`?

Comment: You may use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. You may check `SUM(groups.name = 'B') = 0`. You may use another technique.

Comment: @Akina why not add that as an answer - that's not really a comment.

Comment: @George.Palacios Because I do not see DDLs.

Comment: Could you provide the CREATE TABLE statements please Dangerman? Akina why not ask? That's exactly what the comments are for...

Comment: *Users can belong to multiple groups.* How does this data is stored? Does when user belongs to multiple groups there exists multiple records in `groups` table with the same `user_id` and different `name`? Does there exists a lot of records with the same `name` and different `user_id` in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    id
FROM 
    users as u
    LEFT JOIN groups 
        ON groups.user_id = u.id
WHERE 
    groups.name = 'A'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 
              1 
        FROM 
            groups 
        WHERE 
            user_id = u.id 
            and name IN ('B', 'C', 'D')
    )
```